# Pitest not running with Kotlintest tests

Tags: pitest, kotlintest

I'm using kotlintest in my projects and I want to run mutation testing with pitest.

Already tried using pitest alone and with junit5 plugin, but the result is always:

```
Found  0 tests


================================================================================
- Statistics
================================================================================
>> Generated 610 mutations Killed 0 (0%)
>> Ran 0 tests (0 tests per mutation)
```

I'm using:

- Pitest - 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.4.5'
- Pitest junit5 - 'org.pitest:pitest-junit5-plugin:0.9'
- Koltintest - 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.4.2'

I know kotlintest supports pitest since v3.3.0 (according [here](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/issues/680)) but I don't know how to make it work.

Any ideas how to make it run properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to crack it

For reference see "PIT test-plugins support" section in [gradle pitest plugin documentation](https://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/)

First you need to set up your `buildscript` like this:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   configurations.maybeCreate('pitest')
   dependencies {
       classpath 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.4.5'
       pitest "io.kotlintest:kotlintest-plugins-pitest:3.4.2"
   }
}
```

Then you should set PIT plugin name in `pitest` block

```
pitest {
    testPlugin = 'KotlinTest'
    // rest of your pitest configuration
}
```

After that it should work. Hope this helps!